# jQuery Slideshow (Ryan Florence) Not Working on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have been trying to get a jQuery slideshow (on click) working for a while now and can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I'm working with Ryan Florence's jQuery slideshow nav here:

http://ryanflorence.com/jquery-slideshow/demos/slideshownav/

I've put together a jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hAvXt/3/

I've made sure to include the jQuery UI. There are three javascript files incorporated in his example on his site (demo.js, jquery.rf.slideshow.js, jquery.rf.slideshownav.js). I've taken them all and put them into the javascript section of the JSFiddle.

Basically, when I click on the correct button, it updates the 'slideshow' div to the right content but it's not giving me the transition. At first I thought it was because I was using 'divs' instead of images but I've used his simpler slideshows in the past with divs and it works fine. Thanks so much for the help.

This is my nav bar:

```
<div class="slideshow" id="slideshow" style="width:1105px; height:1402px;">
<div id="red" style="background-color:red;height:1402px; width:1105px;">TEST 1</div>
<div id="green" style="background-color:green;height:1402px; width:1105px;">TEST 2</div>
<div id="blue" style="background-color:blue;height:1402px; width:1105px;">TEST 3</div>
</div>
```

And this is the implementation of the jQuery function:

```
$(function(){
  $('#slideshow').slideshownav({
    transition: 'push(#{direction})',
    mode: 'vertical',
    navSelector: '> ul > li > a',
    duration: 400,
    autoPlay: false
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it set up weird (for anyone who has this problem in the future). With that slideshow, the actual anchor href doesn't do anything which was confusing in the source code on the site for this demo.

It has to do with the order of the anchor tags and the order of the slides. The first one corresponds to the first one, etc.